# How to set List element property with stream?

Tags: java, list, sorting, stream, element

I have a simple demand for java8 stream, here's the situation:

For now, the way to solve this is sorting the list and then set the rank property by index,
so is there any better way to solve this by using java8 stream? Please help, thanks a lot!

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int score;
    private int rank;

    public Student(String name, int score) {
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student s1 = new Student("jack", 98);
        Student s2 = new Student("jason", 86);
        Student s3 = new Student("john", 80);

        List<Student> studentList = Arrays.asList(s1, s2, s3);
        // how to set rank property by score in each student with stream?

    }
}
```

Comment: While it is possible to solve this with streams, as the answer by Bohemian shows, "better" is a matter of opinion here. Both sorting and counting are inherently stateful operations, but streams work best when elements can be processed independently.

Answer (score 3):

The stream element index is not available, which makes sense because streams are built to process elements without context of other elements.

However, you can do it:

```java
List<Student> studentList = Arrays.asList(s1, s2, s3);
AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger();
studentList.stream()
  .sorted(Comparator.comparing(s -> -s.score)) // sort highest first
  .forEachOrdered(s -> s.rank = index.getAndIncrement());
```

This ranks from zero to n-1. To rank from 1 to n change `getAndIncrement` to `incrementAndGet`.